# Java convert from String to integer

Tags: java

I have a String 2D array with some words that I search with JComboBox for certain word at the beginning of the line. What I need is to search that same word by its index. But right now I can only search it using .equals method comparing two Strings.

Example:

```
String [][]array = new String[arraySize][];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
      {
          if(array[i] != null) 
          {
              if(array[i][0].equals(index)) // how can I use = index???
              {
```

This is my homework.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need `i`?

Comment: "*search that same word by its index*"  What does it actually mean?

Comment: A `JComoboBox` has `getSelectedItem` and `getSelectedIndex`. Maybe that was meant. If the items array of the JCombo is somehow in your 2D array, you might do something like `array[index][0]`. Read your assignment

Comment: I'm trying to replace .equals(index) with = index. So I can find value by it's index not by name. I'm aware of getSelectedIndex() method. But how do I use it with String???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If index is a `String` you can use something like this to convert it to `String` first and then compare:

```
Integer iInt = Integer.parseInt(array[i][0]);
if(iInt  == index){
  .....
}
```

Comment: Gives me error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Integer. Array[i][0] is String and I'm trying to = to Integer.

Comment: at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)